# how to apply validation in angular js without form and check all the fileds should filled or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a div in which i am not using the form tag and submit the form on ng-click button but how can i apply the validation of given filed in angulrjs. and check all the fields filled or not.

```
<div ng-controller="AddNewvisaController">
 <!-- <form name =""> -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="visa.requirement">
       <select ng-model="visa.country">
         <option value="1">abc<option>
         <option value="2">xyz<option>
          <option value="3">pqrs<option>
       </select>
     <button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitvisa()">Submit</button>

   <!-- </form> -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `ng-form` directive ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)). Place it together with your controller and the controller will have a form-type object (with `$error`, `$valid` etc properties) in its scope:

```
<div ng-controller="AddNewvisaController" ng-form="formName">
```

(It will place the form in the scope of the controller under the name `formName`.)

It can be used directly from the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" data-ng-click="submitvisa()" ng-disabled="formName.$invalid">Submit</button>
```